# Count and categorize with awk

Tags: awk

I have an input file `p.txt` that I want to count and categorize, I seem not to be getting the desired output.

**Input file:**

```
A1 G1 C1 F1
A2 G1 C1 F1
A3 G1 C1 F2
A4 G1 C2 F2
A7 G1 C2 F2
A8 G1 C2 F3
A11 G1 C2 F3
A23 G1 C2 F3
B4 G1 C2 F3
AC4 G2 C3 F4
B6 G2 C4 F4
BB5 G2 C4 F4
A25 G2 C5 F4
B13 G2 C5 F5
D12 G2 C5 F5
D2 G2 C5 F5
B89 G2 C5 F6
B44 G2 C5 F6
```

**Desired output:**

```
G1(9)
F1(2)
C1=A1,A2

F2(3)
C1=A3
C2=A4,A7

F3(4)
C2=A8,A11,A23,B4


G2(9)
F4(4)
C3=AC4
C4=B6,BB5
C5=A25

F5(3)
C5=B13,D12,D2

F6(2)
C5=B89,B44
```

I tried this:

```
awk '{
    D[$2]++
    A[$4]++
    B[$4 FS $3] = B[$4 FS $3] ? B[$4 FS $3] "," $1 : $1
    if(!tmp[$4 FS $3]++)order[++c]=$4 FS $3
}

function orderp(subs,mains){
    for(j in B){
        if(j==subs){
            split(j,X)
            if(X[1]==mains)
                print X[2]"="B[j]
        }
    }
}

END{
    for(i in D){
        print i"("D[i]")"
        for(i in A){
            print i"("A[i]") "
            for(m=1;m<=c;m++){ orderp(order[m],i) }
            print ""
        }
    }
}
' p.txt
```

I am not getting the desired output
This is what I get:

```
G1(9)
F1(2)
C1=A1,A2

F2(3)
C1=A3
C2=A4,A7

F3(4)
C2=A8,A11,A23,B4

F4(4)
C3=AC4
C4=B6,BB5
C5=A25

F5(3)
C5=B13,D12,D2

F6(2)
C5=B89,B44

G2(9)
F1(2)
C1=A1,A2

F2(3)
C1=A3
C2=A4,A7

F3(4)
C2=A8,A11,A23,B4

F4(4)
C3=AC4
C4=B6,BB5
C5=A25

F5(3)
C5=B13,D12,D2

F6(2)
C5=B89,B44
```

Comment: `A1 G1 C1 F1`
`A2 G1 C1 F1`
`A3 G1 C1 F2`
`A4 G1 C2 F2`
`A7 G1 C2 F2`
`A8 G1 C2 F3`
`A11 G1 C2 F3`
`A23 G1 C2 F3`
`B4 G1 C2 F3`
`AC4 G2 C3 F4`
`B6 G2 C4 F4`
`BB5 G2 C4 F4`
`A25 G2 C5 F4`
`B13 G2 C5 F5`
`D12 G2 C5 F5`
`D2 G2 C5 F5`
`B89 G2 C5 F6`
`B44 G2 C5 F6`

Comment: This is relatively complex for a "why isn't my program working?" type question. I suspect you'll find more people willing to help if you show more specifically what's failing in the output you're getting now, how you've tried to debug it and where you get stuck.

Comment: So your actual output is quite close, only that you are not restricting the "F" values that don't correspond to the current "G" value. I mean, if you only printed F1, F2, and F3 after G1, and only F4, F5, and F6 after G2, it would be perfect. Is that where you are stuck? Is there somewhere in your code that you're already trying to do that?

Comment: If you reduce your example to, say, 6 lines you'll get a lot more people interested in trying to understand it so they can help you.

Comment: @jas, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `G` specific sub array. Here's a fix for your code:

```
awk '{
    D[$2]++
    A[$2 FS $4]++
    B[$2 FS $4 FS $3] = B[$2 FS $4 FS $3] ? B[$2 FS $4 FS $3] "," $1 : $1
    if(!tmp[$2 FS $4 FS $3]++)order[++c]=$2 FS $4 FS $3
}

function orderp(subs,mains){
    for(j in B){
        if(j==subs){
            split(j,X)
            if(X[1] FS X[2] == mains)
                print X[3]"="B[j]
        }
    }
}

END{
    for(k in D){
        print k"("D[k]")"
        for(i in A){
          split(i,X)
          if(k == X[1]){
            print X[2]"("A[i]") "
            for(m=1;m<=c;m++){ orderp(order[m],i) }
            print ""
          }
        }
    }
}
' p.txt
```